# How to disable change of directory?

Tags: fb-hydra

How to disable change of directory?

Currently, all the relative paths in my config are interpreted relative to the hydra output folder, not relative to current working folder.

I'd like to be able to disable this options somehow please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can override the `hydra.run.dir` to `.` for now.
2. You can also translate the paths to be relative to the original working directory (see [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory)).
3. You can also change your relative config paths to be relative to the original working directory (see [Example link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/97d56fc82050d9f7da0a8583b0ba3a39e6923269/tools/configen/conf/configen.yaml#L3)).
   Example:

```yaml
configen:
  # output directory
  output_dir: ${hydra:runtime.cwd}/example
```

In 1.1 I have plans add more control over this behavior ([issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/910))